# Нужно вывести 10 случайных чисел определенного диапазона, как найти минимальное и максимальное значение?

Tags: алгоритм, случайные-числа

Пока что накидал просто вывод десяти чисел из диапазона, как сделать, чтобы определялось максимальное и минимальное рандомное число?

```
import java.util.Random;


    Random generator = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int randomInt = generator.nextInt(34 - -25) + -25;
        System.out.println(randomInt);
    }
```

Comment: Запомнили первое в переменные max и min. Начиная со второго в цикле сравниваете эти переменные со введенным значением. Если max меньше текущего значения, то меняете значение max на текущее. По аналогии поступаете с min.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов интересно, а можно ли получить такое случайное число за один вызов метода random? Хммммм

Comment: цель добиться определения минимального и максимального значений в не зависимости от крайних значений, то есть относительно других рандомных чисел

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов метод рандом не позволяет сравнивать свои значения, возникает ошибка

Comment: Какие значения? вы получаете текущее значение в int randomInt. заведите еще int min, int max и сравнивайте с ними.

Comment: @vitidev напишите код пожалуйста а то я так еще долго тупить буду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написан в online редакторе, java ide нет у меня.

```
import java.util.Random;

// one class needs to have a main() method
public class HelloWorld
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Random generator = new Random();
    int min = generator.nextInt(34 - -25) + -25;
    int max = min;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) { //первая итерация была выше. значит тут меньше
        int randomInt = generator.nextInt(34 - -25) + -25;
        System.out.println(randomInt);

        if(randomInt < min)
          min = randomInt;

        if(randomInt > max)
          max = randomInt;
    }
    System.out.println("min:"+min+" max"+max);
  }
}
```

Comment: "первая итерация была выше"? А где тогда печать результата этой первой итерации?

Comment: @AnT я просто показал пример, а не решил за автора его проблему.

Comment: Нет, вы именно решили за автора его проблему. Или вы хотите сказать, что благодаря одной забытой строчке, ваше решение становится "просто примером"?

Comment: @AnT Проблема автора - подсчет мин/макс на лету. А  не вывод рэндомных значений в консоль. Я привел пример этого подсчета. Вы же не думаете, что программа автора называется HelloWorld ). И на этом сайте любой код суть пример. Сайт такой.